# Python data validation not working as intended

Tags: python, validation

Python 3.8.12

The intended goal of this code is to allow the user to select a "beef", "chicken", "tofu", or "none" sandwich. If the user does not enter one of those options, it will prompt them again to select a sandwich. If they do enter one of these options, then it will continue on with the code.

It is not working properly. It will not accept any input, valid or not. All input causes the program to prompt the user again, rather then moving on with the program if it is valid.

```
sandwich_choice = input("Select sandwich: ")
while sandwich_choice != "chicken" or sandwich_choice != "beef" or sandwich_choice != "tofu" or sandwich_choice != "none":
    sandwich_choice = input("\x1b[30;41m[!]\x1b[0mSelect sandwich: ")
else:
    pass
print("Sandwich selection is", sandwich_choice)
```

Comment: You probably want  "and" instead of "or" in the while loop.

Comment: Even better is `while sandwich_choice not in ('chicken','beef','tofu','none'):`, and of course you don't need the `else` clause at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With modified logic:

```
sandwich_choice = input("Select sandwich: ")
while sandwich_choice not in ('chicken', 'beef', 'tofu', 'none'):
    sandwich_choice = input("\x1b[30;41m[!]\x1b[0mSelect sandwich: ")
else:
    pass
print("Sandwich selection is", sandwich_choice)
```

Answer (score 1):

A better way would be:

```py
sandwich_choice = ""
while True:
   sandwich_choice = input("blah blah blah")
   if sandwich_choice == "beef" or sandwich_choice == "chicken" or sandwich_choice == "tofu" or sandwich_choice == "none":
       break
print("Sandwich selection is",sandwich_choice)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with

```
 sandwich_choice = input("Select sandwich: ")
    list_sandwich = ['chicken', 'beef', 'tofu', 'none']
    while sandwich_choice not in list_sandwich:
        sandwich_choice = input("\x1b[30;41m[!]\x1b[0mSelect sandwich: ")
    else:
        pass
    print("Sandwich selection is", sandwich_choice)
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on Carl_M's implementation

```
sandwich_choice = input("Select sandwich: ")
while sandwich_choice not in ('chicken', 'beef', 'tofu', 'none'):
        sandwich_choice = input("\x1b[30;41m[!]\x1b[0mSelect sandwich: ")
else:
        print("Sandwich selection is", sandwich_choice)
```